# How to POST values stored in href link in one page to the next php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, post, onclick

I have several links in a HTML/PHP page and I want to pass the value stored in the link when they are clicked to the next PHP page via `$_POST` (I know how to do it with `$_GET` but that is not what I want).

I know I need to use javascript/jquery and I have tried a lot of different things but I haven't been able to get it working. I can add an `onclick` attribute to `href`, if it helps to solve the problem.

INSIDE "page1.php" or "page1.html"

```
// Send the values of variables var1, var2, etc. to the new PHP page...
<div class="super">
   <a href="page2c.php" class="top" id="var1" value="100">good</a> 
</div>
<div class="super">
   <a href="page2c.php" class="top" id="var2" value="200">better</a> 
</div>
<div class="super">
   <a href="page2c.php" class="top" id="var3" value="300">best</a> 
</div>
<script>    
  (function() {
     $("#id").on("click",function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); 
       $.post(this.href,function(value) {
         $(".top").html(value);
       });
     });
   });
</script>
```

INSIDE "page2.php"

```
<?php
    // Retrieve the URL variables (using PHP and jquery).

   $val_1= $_POST['var1'];
   $val_2= $_POST['var2'];
   $val_3= $_POST['var3'];

    //to test we retrieved the values from page1
    echo "value of var1 is: ".$var_1;
?>
```

Comment: First get the values using jquery and use ajax to send the values to next page

Comment: You are passing `#id` but there is no element with `id="id"`, Did you mean `$("#var1").on("click",` or `$(".top").on("click",`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because you're not sending any data in the `$.post` call. Presumably you want to send the id/value of the `a` elements.

Firstly, note that `value` is not a valid attribute of an `a` element. I'd suggest changing this to a `data` attribute to avoid validation issues.

Secondly, to send the data in the request you can build an object, like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="super">
  <a href="page2c.php" class="top" id="var1" data-value="100">good</a>
</div>
<div class="super">
  <a href="page2c.php" class="top" id="var2" data-value="200">better</a>
</div>
<div class="super">
  <a href="page2c.php" class="top" id="var3" data-value="300">best</a>
</div>

<button id="id">Click me!</button>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#id").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = {};
      $('a').each(function() {
        data[this.id] = $(this).data('value');
      });      
      console.log(data);
      
      $.post(this.href, data, function(value) {
        $(".top").html(value);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

** Update **

> When any of the href link is clicked, page2.php is opened and based on which linked is clicked e.g. 'link3 above' which has a value 300, the page2.php does something based on that value. I don't want to pass all values of the links at once

In this case you can just read the `data-value` from the element and send it in the request and read it back in the PHP:

```
$(function() {
  $(".super a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(this.href, {
      value: $(this).data('value')
    }, function(value) {
      $(".top").html(value);
    });
  });
});
```

```js
<?php
   $val = $_POST['value'];
   echo "value of var1 is: ".$val;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt solution. I am trying to test the script. how do I retrieve the value on 2nd page, is it  $var_1 =$_POST[".top"] or something else?

Comment: You use exactly what you had before, `$_POST['var1']`, `$_POST['var2']` etc

Comment: I get an error as: "undefined index: var1 in page2.php" and there is nothing on console log. the only thing is different I don't have <button id="id">Click me!</button>. As mentioned the links are clickable individually and cannot add a button there.

Comment: So you only click the one button? In that case how are you expecting to receive three values?

Comment: no. when any of the href link is clicked, page2.php is opened and based on which linked is clicked individually e.g. 'link3 above' which has a value 300, the page2.php does something based on that value. I don't want to pass all values of the links at once.

Comment: That makes more sense. I updated the answer for you.

Comment: Appreciate your help, Rory but still getting the same error. nothing is passed to the second page.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to update the selector to `.super a`. Try now

Comment: the last change did not work at all. it opened up page2 inside page1 and every click on anything, reloaded the page again and there is no value passed on to page2 yet.

Comment: I'm unable to help then as I cannot see a reason for this to not work. All I can suggest is you check the console for errors and try to debug it from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. really appreciated. I will find a way.

Answer (score 1):

```
var value= $(this).attr('value');
```

After that pass thus value to ajax function.

**Example:**

```
var record_id=jQuery(this).attr('data-key');
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType:'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{
                        record_id:record_id,
                    }
```

Comment: How would they pass this variable?

Comment: Given that `this` would be an `a` element `val()` won't work: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hz2xvahp/

Comment: Is the data JSON or is it a JS object?

Comment: use updated example answer above. Or u can give data attribute to anchor tag.